# Book Search: Last humans (?) on Mars

Tags: story-identification

I have been looking for a book I saw a while back, and for the life of me cannot remember the title, or author. I haven't read the book, its relatively new (post 2010 by approximation).

Focal point is this: Something happened to the sun (expansion being my guess) and it has swallowed earth. The humans, predicting this event, moved to Mars to avoid the initial subsumation of the earth. Now the sun continues to expand to the point it will destroy Mars. Mars wasn't a long-term destination anyway, so they continue onwards. The main character is some scientists' kid who stayed with his parents as the 'rearguard'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Last Day on Mars" by  Kevin Emerson:

> It is Earth year 2213—but, of course, there is no Earth anymore. Not
>   since it was burned to a cinder by the sun, which has mysteriously
>   begun the process of going supernova. The human race has fled to Mars,
>   but this was only a temporary solution while we have prepared for a
>   second trip: a one-hundred-fifty-year journey to a distant star, our
>   best guess at where we might find a new home.
>
> Liam Saunders-Chang is one of the last humans left on Mars. The son of
>   two scientists who have been racing against time to create technology
>   vital to humanity’s survival, Liam, along with his friend Phoebe, will
>   be on the last starliner to depart before Mars, like Earth before it,
>   is destroyed.
>
> Or so he thinks. Because before this day is over, Liam and Phoebe will
>   make a series of profound discoveries about the nature of time and
>   space and find out that the human race is just one of many in our
>   universe locked in a dangerous struggle for survival.

[https://www.amazon.com/Last-Mars-Chronicle-Dark-Star/dp/0062306715](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062306715)